# c# parsing null to int from api fails

Tags: c#

I am trying to parse a null from our api into an int like this:

API:

```
"thresholdMax": 10,
                    "thresholdAvg": null,
                    "thresholdMin": 40
```

Datamodel:

```
public int thresholdMax { get; set; }
        public int thresholdAvg
        { 
            get { return thresholdAvg; }
            set
            {
                try
                {
                    thresholdAvg = value;
                }
                catch
                {
                    thresholdAvg = 0;
                }
            }

        }
        public int thresholdMin { get; set; }
```

But it fails saying it cannot parse null to int. I though however that with how I am setting these values, it should work.

What is the best practice, if I dont want to convert the type to string?

Comment: Value types, such as `int`, cannot be set to null. Do you want to allow `thresholdAvg` to be null?

Comment: A setter on an average, a max < min... there are many many questions as to what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: it does. feel free to answer my posst :)

Comment: You can use Nullable value types. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types

Comment: In addition, your current try/catch is not doing what you think it should do. `thresholdAvg = value;` can't throw an exception. Remember there's a difference between a json property being `null` and a json property being excluded entirely. Also, using a property inside itself will cause a StackOverflow Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to allow `null` values you could easily do:

```
public int? thresholdAvg { get; set; }
```